# Search array for none exact title

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have this piece of code which I have had to develop form batch files. That was out old system.

The code below scans `./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/` and lists all the files that are have an MP4 extension. It works great however, I need to filter the results.

`$post_title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());` is the title of the WORDPRESS Post. For example, in this case it is: **V000-TEST READ ALL**

The filter should be able to filter the following variations of **V000-TEST READ ALL**

- V001-TEST READ ALL
- V002-TEST READ ALL
- V003 -TEST READ ALL
- V004- TEST READ ALL
- V005- TEST READ ALL
- V006-TEST READ ALL - Some Extra Information
- V007-TEST READ ALL - There will always be a - for extra info
- V008-TEST READ ALL - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283)
- V009-TEST READ ALL - Final Version

AS you can see, the only thing that stays the same is the title. **TEST READ ALL**

I am not sure where to start let alone what to write. PHP is not the path I walk down, although learning.

---

```
$path = "./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";
$webdir = site_url()."/wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";
$webdirclean = site_url();
$post_title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());


$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = array();
$notAllowedExtension = array('jpg', 'vtr', 'html', 'htm' );

foreach($iterator as $file){

if(!in_array($file->getExtension(), $notAllowedExtension) && !$file->isDir())

$files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getPathname();
}

ksort($files);

// Filter Array based on name, including varation name

$files = array_filter($files, function($post_title)
{
    return preg_match('#^V\d{3}\s*-\s*$post_title(\s*-\s*[^\s].+)?$#', $post_title);
});

echo '<h2>After filter</h2>';
echo implode('<br>', $files);


//echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>";


foreach($files as $file => $date){
$title=$files[$file]; 

$cleantitle = basename($title, ".mp4");

if( $i==$autoplay ) $file_main = $title; 
$output .= "" . PHP_EOL . 
"<tr> 
<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$webdirclean$title')\"> $cleantitle (Click Me)</a>
</td>
    <td>NA</td>     

  </tr>"
. PHP_EOL;
$i++;
}
```

---

As a refference, and I am not sure if it is any good, here is the batch code I made before which does what I needed.

```
rem Separate file name in parts delimited by "-. "
rem and use each part to test the element in folder array
set "name=%file_name%"
:nextPart
for /F "tokens=1* delims=-. " %%a in ("%name%") do (
   if not defined folder[%%a] (
      set "name=%%b"
      goto nextPart
   ) else (
      set "folder_path=!folder[%%a]!"
      goto pathFound
   )
)

rem Search the elements of folder array in the file_name
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set folder[') do (
   if "!file_name:%%a=!" neq "%file_name%" (
      set "folder_path=%%b"
      goto pathFound
   )
)
echo ERROR: Folder path not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for filtering the titles:

```
<?php
$post_titles =
[
    'V001-TEST READ ALL',
    'V002-TEST READ ALL',
    'V003 -TEST READ ALL',
    'V004- TEST READ ALL',
    'V005- TEST READ ALL',
    'V006-TEST READ ALL - Some Extra Information',
    'V007-TEST READ ALL - There will always be a - for extra info',
    'V008-TEST READ ALL - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283)',
    'V009-TEST READ ALL - Final Version',

    // Some faulty titles:
    'V009-TEST READ NONE',
    'V 001-TEST READ ALL',
    'V001-TEST READ ALL - ',
    'V001- - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283)'
];

echo '<h2>Before filter</h2>';
echo implode('<br>', $post_titles);

$var = 'TEST READ ALL'; // The fixed portion of the string

$post_titles = array_filter($post_titles, function($post_title) use($var)
{
    return preg_match("#^V\d{3}\s*-\s*$var(\s*-\s*[^\s].+)?$#", $post_title);
});

echo '<h2>After filter</h2>';
echo implode('<br>', $post_titles);
?>
```

**Output:**

```html
<h2>Before filter</h2>V001-TEST READ ALL<br>V002-TEST READ ALL<br>V003 -TEST READ ALL<br>V004- TEST READ ALL<br>V005- TEST READ ALL<br>V006-TEST READ ALL - Some Extra Information<br>V007-TEST READ ALL - There will always be a - for extra info<br>V008-TEST READ ALL - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283)<br>V009-TEST READ ALL - Final Version<br>V009-TEST READ NONE<br>V 001-TEST READ ALL<br>V001-TEST READ ALL - <br>V001- - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283)<h2>After filter</h2>V001-TEST READ ALL<br>V002-TEST READ ALL<br>V003 -TEST READ ALL<br>V004- TEST READ ALL<br>V005- TEST READ ALL<br>V006-TEST READ ALL - Some Extra Information<br>V007-TEST READ ALL - There will always be a - for extra info<br>V008-TEST READ ALL - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283)<br>V009-TEST READ ALL - Final Version
```

Comment: What a fantastic piece of code. I am testing it out now. !!!! Thank you Midas!!! I am trying out all variations.

Comment: Hello @Midas, I have incorporated you code to the best on my knowledge. Have been trying for the last 4 hours. However, I am not sure if it is correct. Furthermore, `$files` have the full address of the files which is need for the rest of the script to function. I am not quite sure how to integrate it. Any help is more than welcome. Thank you

Comment: Also, as a side note, I am not sure if the .mp4 & .mp3 extensions would cause a problem. Thanks

Comment: Also, I noticed `return preg_match('#^V\d{3}\s*-\s*TEST READ ALL(\s*-\s*[^\s].+)?$#', $post_title);` **TEST READ ALL** can change when ever I change to a different post. So, in another post, it could be **PROJECT 009 BLACK HAWK**.

Comment: Hi @Arthor. You can use a variable inside the regular expression, so it would become: `"#^V\d{3}\s*-\s*$var(\s*-\s*[^\s].+)?$#"`. Notice that you need double quotes "" here.

Comment: As for file extensions, you can remove the file extension from a string using `$filename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME)`

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I have set `$var = "TEST READ ALL";` and used the `"#^V\d{3}\s*-\s*$var(\s*-\s*[^\s].+)?$#"`. However, it returns: After filter
V001- - This work is complex Bla bla ABAK (19283).

`$var` is effectively `$post_title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());`. Right?

Comment: @Arthor Ok. I think you need to add `use($var)` after the anonymous function in `array_filter`, because `$var` is defined in another scope. I'll change that in my answer.